# Code does not reflect updates to category name in each text box

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

the code does not allow me to update/edit the name in each text box. I've reviewed the code several times but could not find any errors. Grateful for any help. Thanks.

THE HTML

```
            /*
             *  Confirm category deletion
             */

           $("body").on("click", "a.delete", function () {          
                if (!confirm("Confirm page deletion")) return false;
            });

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            /*
             *  Rename Category
             */

            var originalTextBoxValue;

            $("table#pages input.text-box").dblclick(function () {
                originalTextBoxValue = $(this).val();
                $(this).attr("readonly", false);
            });

            $("table#pages input.text-box").keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $(this).blur();
                }
            });

            $("table#pages input.text-box").blur(function () {

                var $this = $(this);
                var ajaxdiv = $this.parent().find(".ajaxdivtd");
                var newCatName = $this.val();
                var id = $this.parent().parent.attr("id").substring(3);
                var url = "/admin/shop/RenameCategory";

                if (newCatName.length < 2) {
                    alert("Category name must be at least 2 characters long.");
                    $this.attr("readonly", true);
                    return false;
                }

                $.post(url, { newCatName: newCatName, id: id }, function (data) {
                    var response = data.trim();

                    if (response == "titletaken") {
                        $this.val(originalTextBoxValue);
                        ajaxdiv.html("<span class='alert alert-danger'>That title 
 is taken!</span>").show();
                    } else {
                        ajaxdiv.html("<span class='alert alert-success'>The category name has been changed!</span>").show();
                    }

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        ajaxdiv.fadeOut("fast", function () {
                            ajaxdiv.html("");
                        });
                    }, 2000);
                    }).done(function () {
                        $this.attr("readonly", true);
                });

            });

            ///////////////////////////////////////////

            });

    </script>

\\\
```

Comment: can you describe your problem in detail? Please provide a completed html code for us so that I can test it. Also, I noticed that your html code make some limits about textbox such as  $this.attr("readonly", true);. Try to delete the sentence or change true to false.

Comment: Hi Jack thanks alot for getting back to me. I somehow managed to fix the error but a new one has presented itself. :-/